# How to run debugger in mixed JS/TS project with .ts import to .js?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm writing a code in a big JS project for Node, but I want to use TS in it.
It's pure tsc, no bundlers.
So I have a situation with an entry `app.js` file which imports `module1.ts`. Everything works fine in the runtime but I can't run live debugger in VS Code. I've tried several ways:

1. If I try

```
const q =  require('./module1');
```

I get

```
error Exception has occurred: Error: Cannot find module './module1'
```

2. If I try

```
const q =  require('./module1.ts');
```

I get

```log
Exception has occurred: ...\module1.ts:1
export default () => {
^^^^^^
```

3. If I try

```
import q from './module1';
```

I get

```log
(node:1092) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
import q from './module1';
^^^^^^
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Is it debugguble in any way?

Comment: When you run a `.js` file with tsc, you are basically letting `tsc` pretend it's a Typescript file. If you want a true Javascript file to use your Typescript modules, you need to import the compiled files, not the source files.

Comment: @Evert Do I need to do it just once when I import `.ts` into `.js`, or all down the chain of imports `js < ts < ts < ts`?
Is it okay solution at all? I never met it before.
I mean, I don't want to make code ugly just for debugging.

Comment: No, you should ideally just use `.ts` everywhere, but your code should run without `tsc`. If you do want to mix ts/js, make sure you set `allowJs` to true, and you run your code from your build directory, not your soruce directory.

Comment: @Evert but I want to debug the TS code, not compiled JS.

Comment: You can only debug compiled code (js) but your debugger can figure out which js lines correspond to which ts line using sourcemaps

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile before debug?

If a Javascript file named 'module1.js' exists, the first error info is not expected.

You can write config files for debugger to avoid compile manually.

```
// .vscode/tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "tsc",
            "label": "Compile TypeScript"
        }
    ]
}
//.vscode/launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\main.js",
            "preLaunchTask": "Compile TypeScript"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your ts file is written in esm while nodejs use cjs by default, so you will see the 2nd and the 3rd error info. If you write cjs in ts file, it would work.

Comment: Yes, I have pre-launch task already.